# Detect focus on browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

Is there a way to detect when focus has been put onto the address-bar or the browser-search-bar?

I ask because I am trying to keep focus on one element in my document, but adding a `blur()` listener to that element (which calls `focus()` on that same element) works too well in [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) Mac -- you can't put focus on the address-bar when you `setFocus` with a timeout of 0 (necessary for a plugin).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it is not possible

Answer (score 3):

You can only work with the DOM.

If you want to access address bar, you need a control running in the browser or your own toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

why not check when the desired element has lost focus? and work your way from there?
and what i meant was using the .focusout() event, instead of .blur() since it behaves different.

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/