# windown.onblur called on address bar click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I noticed a strange thing in IE8, FF3+, Chrome 3+ that when I click on the address bar or location bar, the window.onblur gets fired.

Is it normal?

Is there a way by which I may be able to know (through javascript) that the user has clicked address bar?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is normal. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501002/detect-focus-on-browser-address-bar

Comment: I want to know if the user has clicked address bar or not. I think that it is not normal because the address bar lies inside window. When I click on scrollbars or top pane(which has cross button), i dont get window.onlblur. So, this is pretty strange. Can you please suggest a solution or work around?