# Google Chrome address bar focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, focus, address-bar, omnibox

I am making a simple Google Chrome extension and I was wondering, is there a way to understand in my content script when the focus is on the Chrome's address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Generic JavaScript answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501002/detect-focus-on-browser-address-bar).

Chrome does not present any specific API to expand your capability; there is the [`omnibox` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox), but for security/privacy reasons you only start to get events from that after the user enters a keyword you specify in the manifest.

So, still no.

Comment: Someone needs to put this omnibar monopoly to a stop.